# combining txt files and counting words

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

```
def word_counter(s)
    word_list=s.split()
    return len(word_list)

f=open("a.txt")
total=0
for i in f.readlines():
    total+=word_counter(i)

print(total)
```

if I want to count number of alphabet(without blank), number of word used and average length of each 'a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'd.txt', 'e.txt'. At last, I want to get a 'total.txt' of all txt combined.

I dont know how to do more..
please help

Comment: You need to read the files `a.txt`, `b.txt` etc.., and open a new file `total.txt` to which you can write the data. However, you can also use `cat file1 file2 ...` to concatenate all the files and create `total.txt` without python

Answer (score 1):

You actually have the concept right. Just need to add a little more to reach your desired output.

Remember when you use `f = open("a.txt")`, make sure you call `f.close()`. Or, use the `with` keyword, like I did in the example. It automatically closes the file for you, even if you forget to.

I won't give the exact code as it is, but will provide the steps so that you learn the concepts.

1. Put all the .txt files names in a list.
   Example, `list_FileNames = ["a.txt", "b.txt"]`
2. Then open each file, and get the entire file into a string.

   `for file in list_FileNames:
       with open(file, 'r') as inFile:
           myFileInOneString = inFile.read().replace('\n', '')`
3. You have the right function to count words. For characters: `len(myFileInOneString) - myFileInOneString.count(' ')`
4. Save all these values into a varible and write to another file. Check how to write to a file: [How to Write to a File in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)